# How to set notification PushPlugin in cordova?

Tags: android, push-notification, cordova-3, phonegap-pushplugin

My question is how to configure the notification, ie to have a title and a message, because it only gets me the message but no title. in file "GCMIntentService.java" plugin I found three variables, title, message and msgcnt, could tell me how each is used and that it serves?

Here the data are received bad about that uses a default value

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    String message = extras.getString("message");
    if (message != null) {
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your php should looks like this.

```
$fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $regs_ids,
                'data' => array( "message" => $message, "title" => $title ),
            );
```

Passing the parameter title in the array should works.